# Use "bad Ethernet frame counter" to debug Cat7 wiring issues

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, wiring

This question is about cabling quality problems in a Cat7 (10Gbps) network installation in an industrial environment, where fiddly [M12 x-coded 8-pin connectors](https://b2b.harting.com/ebusiness/en_us/M12-SD-male-X-cod-8-pol-crimp-flange/21038811807) are used. In some cases, we are also running PoE over the cables.

During the installation of the (pre-measured / certified) cables, single pins within the M12 connector can get bent or don't contact properly. As a result, the LINK/ACT LEDs are blinking fine and PoE supply is okay, but at a closer look the transmission mode falls back from the desired *10000Full* to *10Half*, combined with huge packet loss.

Looking at the *bad (Ethernet) frame counters* on both ends of the cables, we often see an asymmetry:

- ~0 bad frames from A to B
- 10000s of bad frames B to A (opposite direction)

At a first glance, this sounds to me as if this could indicate a problem on a certain Rx or Tx wire pair within the cable. But I am really not an expert in Ethernet physics.

**So, question: Is there any way to conclude which of the 8 pins or wires in the Cat7 cable are defective, from the observed asymmetry in bad Ethernet frame counters?**

*I know that you can actually measure the wires. That's been done. But the problems only arise once the connectors get plugged. So I am explicitly looking for other debugging means.*

Comment: If the wires test OK, perhaps the problem is with the connectors? Maybe a wire isn't making good contact, or the connector is just miswired?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - The problem is _definitely_ with the connectors, and I know that it is almost certainly caused by pin(s) not having proper contact. The question is: Which one(s)? Can the bad frame counters tell me?